# Loading UI file with QWebengine through class using PyQt

Tags: python, class, pyqt, qtwidgets, qwebengineview

I'm trying to load a UI file using `PyQt5.uic.loadUi` which has `QWebEngineView`, but my code currently loads a blank QT form.

It was working before until I changed the way classes were referencing each other. I'm new to working with classes and cannot understand the correct use of self and parent.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>
<div id="output">Test page</div>
</body></html>
"""
text1 = 'demo text'

class Ui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('demoweb.ui', self)
        ctr = self.findChild(QWidget,"webViewContainer")
        self.browser = ctr.findChild(QWebEngineView,"webEngineView")
        self.edit = self.findChild(QLineEdit,"lineEdit")

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        ui = Ui()
        self._ui = ui
        ui.browser.setHtml(html)
        page = ui.browser.page()
        page.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoadFinished)
        ui.edit.setText(text1)
        self._ready = False
    
    def onLoadFinished(self):
        #code to be added
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

demoweb.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect><x>0</x><y>0</y><width>746</width><height>462</height></rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect><x>21</x><y>361</y><width>691</width><height>22</height></rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="webViewContainer" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect><x>10</x><y>10</y><width>711</width><height>331</height></rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QWebEngineView" name="webEngineView">
       <property name="url">
        <url>
         <string>about:blank</string>
        </url>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QWebEngineView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header location="global">QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEngineView</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: add `ui.show()`

Comment: The `UI` class is actually useless (unless you intend to create a *further* new window, but I don't think that's the case). Subclass `Window` from QMainWindow instead of QWidget, remove any reference to `ui`, and just add `uic.loadUi('demoweb.ui', self)` after the `super().__init__(parent)`. All widgets are created as instance attributes using their object name, so you don't need to use `findChild`: the browser will be available as `self.webEngineView`, the line edit as `self.lineEdit`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc, ui.show() made the form visible.

Comment: @musicamante, that's extremely helpful. I've followed all your suggestions and the code is much easier to manage. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved after following suggestions from [musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante)

Thanks [eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc), your suggestion also resolved the problem but was no longer required in the simplified code.

Working code below

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>
<div id="output">Test page</div>
</body></html>
"""
text1 = 'demo text'

class Ui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('demoweb.ui', self)
        ctr = self.findChild(QWidget,"webViewContainer")
        self.browser = ctr.findChild(QWebEngineView,"webEngineView")
        self.edit = self.findChild(QLineEdit,"lineEdit")

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('demoweb.ui', self)
        self.webEngineView.setHtml(html)
        page = self.webEngineView.page()
        page.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoadFinished)
        self.lineEdit.setText(text1)
        self._ready = False
    
    def onLoadFinished(self):
        #code to be added
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```